# Refused to execute inline script on client application

Tags: content-security-policy

I am working on this asp.net applicatio n and everything was working fine but suddenly I started getting the below warning on application deployed on client server
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the followingg Content security policy directive: "script-src".

I googled about this and understood but my question is that why it tarred coming now? Blogs show this error coming from so many years but why I got it only today? What changes would have caused to trigger this on client server? Please help. Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

The perfect solution ia to move all inline scripts and styles to separate files but since its a live application we cannot afford it. We can do it in parallel while keeping rhe application going but now the application is acting wierd. Please tell what can I do as a quick fix to get things going

Comment: If you can't move your code then you'll have to remove your CSP.